# Is it possible to fire a weapon through logic?

Tags: starmade

I'm trying to make rail-docked wings that fold around and do other such stuff, but the weapons will be on it, which happens to be a separate entity to the main ship I'm building. Is there any way to have it so that the main ship has a logic block that is on the flight mode hotbar, which is connected to a wireless logic block, which is connected to another wireless logic block on the wing, which is connected to the cannon...?

To put it simply:

**Is it possible to fire a weapon through logic in StarMade?**

I.e. I connect a logic activator to a weapon computer and it fires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply connect any logic signal to the weapon computer and trigger the signal.